# Progress bar visibility after picture is saved

Tags: windows-phone-8, progress-bar

I am able to show the progress indicator while saving am image to media library but I don't know how to change the `IsVisible = false` after the pictures saved. Following is the code I used for it -

```
async void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator();
        progress.IsVisible = true;
        progress.IsIndeterminate = true;
        progress.Text = "saving image...";

        //Save a copy of the image
        using (MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
        {
            var imgStream = (await App.CurrPhoto.RawSession.RenderToJpegAsync()).AsStream();
            library.SavePicture(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString(), imgStream);
        }

        SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, progress);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `ProgressIndicator` before performing the action and then disable it after your save code.

```
ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator();
progress.IsVisible = true;
progress.IsIndeterminate = true;
progress.Text = "saving image...";

//set the indicator before the save code
SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, progress);

//Save a copy of the image
using (MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
{
   var imgStream = (await App.CurrPhoto.RawSession.RenderToJpegAsync()).AsStream();
   library.SavePicture(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString(), imgStream);
}

//disable it
SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, null);
```